# Java can't find local files after calling PrinterJob.getPrinterJob().defaultPage()

Tags: java, file, filepath

I'm really stumped on this issue. I have a problem where Java can't find files in the local directory after calling the method PrinterJob.getPrinterJob().defaultPage();

In fact I've boiled it down to the following simple program:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    File file = new File("test.txt");

    System.out.println("File: " + file.getAbsolutePath() + 
                       " exists=" + file.exists());

    PrinterJob.getPrinterJob().defaultPage();

    System.out.println("File: " + file.getAbsolutePath() + 
                       " exists=" + file.exists());
}
```

Which outputs the following:

```
File: C:\OpenBug\test.txt exists=true
File: C:\OpenBug\test.txt exists=false
```

The java file, the file "test.txt" and the class file all exist in the same directory.

I'm compiling and running the single java file from the command line.

I did a fresh install of 1.6.0_22 on XP today and get the same results.

What could possibly be going on? Is PrinterJob loading some class that is somehow changing my view of the file system?

I added code to my program to dump out my system env. Anything fishy here?

```
awt.toolkit = sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
file.encoding = Cp1252
file.encoding.pkg = sun.io
file.separator = \
java.awt.graphicsenv = sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
java.awt.printerjob = sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
java.class.path = .
java.class.version = 50.0
java.endorsed.dirs = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\lib\endorsed
java.ext.dirs = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\lib\ext;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\lib\ext
java.home = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre
java.io.tmpdir = C:\DOCUME~1\Andrew\LOCALS~1\Temp\
java.library.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin;.;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\b
in;C:\Java\apache-ant-1.8.1\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
java.runtime.version = 1.6.0_22-b04
java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.vendor = Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.specification.version = 1.6
java.vendor = Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.vendor.url = http://java.sun.com/
java.vendor.url.bug = http://java.sun.com/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi
java.version = 1.6.0_22
java.vm.info = mixed mode, sharing
java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.vm.specification.vendor = Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.vm.specification.version = 1.0
java.vm.vendor = Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.vm.version = 17.1-b03
line.separator =

os.arch = x86
os.name = Windows XP
os.version = 5.1
path.separator = ;
sun.arch.data.model = 32
sun.boot.class.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\j
dk1.6.0_22\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program File
s\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\classes
sun.boot.library.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\bin
sun.cpu.endian = little
sun.cpu.isalist = pentium_pro+mmx pentium_pro pentium+mmx pentium i486 i386 i86
sun.desktop = windows
sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeLittle
sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD
sun.jnu.encoding = Cp1252
sun.management.compiler = HotSpot Client Compiler
sun.os.patch.level = Service Pack 3
user.country = US
user.dir = C:\OpenBug
user.home = C:\Documents and Settings\Andrew
user.language = en
user.name = Andrew
user.timezone =
user.variant =
```

Running in verbose mode, you can see the following classes are loaded by the PrintJob

```
[Loaded java.awt.print.PrinterJob from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.print.PrinterJob$1 from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.DisposerTarget from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.print.RasterPrinterJob from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.Toolkit from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.Toolkit$3 from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.ResourceBundle$Control from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.util.CoreResourceBundleControl from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.Arrays$ArrayList from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.ResourceBundle from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.ResourceBundle$1 from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.ResourceBundle$RBClassLoader from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.ResourceBundle$RBClassLoader$1 from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.ResourceBundle$CacheKey from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.ResourceBundle$CacheKeyReference from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.ResourceBundle$LoaderReference from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.ResourceBundle$SingleFormatControl from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.AbstractList$Itr from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.ListResourceBundle from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.resources.awt from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.Toolkit$1 from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.io.FileNotFoundException from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$1 from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.Insets from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.DebugHelper from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.NativeLibLoader from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.DebugHelperStub from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.Toolkit$2 from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.WindowClosingSupport from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.WindowClosingListener from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.ComponentFactory from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.InputMethodSupport from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.SunToolkit from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.windows.WToolkit from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.logging.Logger from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.logging.Handler from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.logging.Level from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.logging.LogManager from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.logging.LogManager$1 from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.logging.LogManager$LogNode from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.logging.LoggingPermission from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.logging.LogManager$Cleaner from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks$1 from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown$Lock from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.IdentityHashMap from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.logging.LogManager$2 from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.Properties$LineReader from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.Hashtable$Enumerator from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.EventObject from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.logging.LogManager$3 from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown$PeerMap from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.WeakHashMap from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.WeakHashMap$Entry from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.FontSupport from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.EventListener from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.DisplayChangedListener from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment$1 from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.io.FilenameFilter from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment$TTFilter from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment$T1Filter from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.windows.WindowsFlags from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.windows.WindowsFlags$1 from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.Transparency from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.Surface from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.SurfaceData from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.lang.IllegalStateException from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.InvalidPipeException from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.NullSurfaceData from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.loops.SurfaceType from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.PixelConverter from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.PixelConverter$Xrgb from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.PixelConverter$Argb from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.PixelConverter$ArgbPre from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.PixelConverter$Xbgr from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.PixelConverter$Rgba from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.PixelConverter$RgbaPre from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.PixelConverter$Ushort565Rgb from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.PixelConverter$Ushort555Rgb from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.PixelConverter$Ushort555Rgbx from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.PixelConverter$Ushort4444Argb from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.PixelConverter$ByteGray from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.PixelConverter$UshortGray from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.PixelConverter$Rgbx from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.PixelConverter$Bgrx from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.PixelConverter$ArgbBm from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.image.ColorModel from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.image.PackedColorModel from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.image.DirectColorModel from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.color.ColorSpace from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.color.ICC_Profile from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.color.ProfileDeferralInfo from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.color.ProfileDeferralMgr from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.color.ICC_ProfileRGB from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.color.ProfileActivator from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.color.ICC_Profile$1 from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.PixelDrawPipe from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.PixelFillPipe from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.ShapeDrawPipe from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.TextPipe from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImagePipe from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.NullPipe from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.image.IndexColorModel from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.ParallelogramPipe from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.LoopPipe from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.OutlineTextRenderer from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.GlyphListPipe from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.GlyphListLoopPipe from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.SolidTextRenderer from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.AATextRenderer from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.LCDTextRenderer from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.CompositePipe from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.AlphaColorPipe from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.PixelToShapeConverter from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.PixelToParallelogramConverter from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.TextRenderer from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.SpanClipRenderer from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.Region from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.RegionIterator from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.Region$ImmutableRegion from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.AlphaPaintPipe from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.SpanShapeRenderer from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.SpanShapeRenderer$Composite from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.GeneralCompositePipe from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.loops.RenderCache from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.loops.RenderCache$Entry from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.Image from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.image.VolatileImage from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.DestSurfaceProvider from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.SunVolatileImage from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.ImageCapabilities from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.SurfaceManager$ImageAccessor from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.Image$1 from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.SurfaceManager from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.image.VolatileSurfaceManager from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.image.ImageObserver from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.MenuContainer from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.Component from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.windows.WObjectPeer from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.peer.ComponentPeer from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.dnd.peer.DropTargetPeer from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.Font from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.geom.AffineTransform from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.font.AttributeValues from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.lang.Enum from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.font.EAttribute from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.text.AttributedCharacterIterator$Attribute from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.lang.Class$4 from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.font.TextAttribute from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.lang.Integer$IntegerCache from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.AWTAccessor$ComponentAccessor from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.Component$1 from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.AWTAccessor from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.AWTEvent from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.RequestFocusController from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.Component$DummyRequestFocusController from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.windows.WToolkit$1 from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.Toolkit$DesktopPropertyChangeSupport from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.ModalityListener from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.SunToolkit$ModalityListenerList from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.SunToolkit$1 from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.MissingResourceException from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.EventQueue from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.Queue from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.AppContext from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.AppContext$1 from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.AppContext$2 from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.PostEventQueue from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.misc.PerformanceLogger from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.misc.PerformanceLogger$TimeData from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.DisposerRecord from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.windows.WToolkit$ToolkitDisposer from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.Disposer from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.java2d.Disposer$1 from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.windows.WToolkit$2 from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.windows.WToolkit$2$1 from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.peer.CanvasPeer from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.windows.WCanvasPeer from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.peer.ContainerPeer from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.peer.PanelPeer from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.windows.WPanelPeer from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.peer.WindowPeer from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.windows.WWindowPeer from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.peer.DialogPeer from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.windows.WPrintDialogPeer from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.beans.PropertyChangeListener from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.windows.WWindowPeer$ActiveWindowListener from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.windows.WWindowPeer$GuiDisposedListener from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.print.Pageable from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.print.Book from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob$HandleRecord from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.print.PageFormat from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.print.Paper from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.Shape from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.geom.RectangularShape from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Double from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\lib\rt.jar]


File: C:\OpenBug\test.txt exists=false


[Loaded java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.IdentityHashMap$Values from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.IdentityHashMap$IdentityHashMapIterator from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.IdentityHashMap$ValueIterator from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.HashMap$KeySet from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.HashMap$HashIterator from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.AppContext$PostShutdownEventRunnable from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.MostRecentKeyValue from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown$1 from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.awt.AWTAccessor$AWTEventAccessor from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.awt.AWTEvent$1 from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.IdentityHashMap$KeySet from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.IdentityHashMap$KeyIterator from shared objects file]
```

Thanks in advance,
Andrew

Comment: I ran the test program and it worked as expected. (not on XP though)..

Comment: Well I changed my default printer and it seems to have fixed the problem. However I'm really stumped how a particular printer driver could cause all my File objects that have been created to become invalid. Additionally I've found if I recreate the file objects after the call to PrinterJob it will find the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the problem quite a while ago and just realized I never provided the answer. The problem was with the printer driver of the default printer. I believe I either upgraded the printer driver or simply changed the default to resolve.

It is however surprising that a printer driver could somehow cause java's view of the file system to become unstable.

Answer (score 1):

Am not very sure that whether your printer or system is remote. You may move your file to java temporary folder and ten you can get the absolute path from right there.

```
File f2 = new File(f1.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Recreating the file in this way does allow it to be found. But why should this be so?